# Setting up sbspace to hold send and receive queues in Informix

Tags: informix

I am missing some steps to achieve Enterprise Replication with Informix regarding disk configuration:

- How to set up sbpaces to hold send and receive queues
- Create dbspace for transaction records
- Define dbspace for syscdr database

I've created two different VMs; each one got CentOS7 Linux System. Then I've installed IDS Developer Edition. My installation is organized as `/mnt/informix` and in `informix/` I have `/product`, `/ids`, `/storage`:

- `/mnt/informix/product` is where am saving installation files.
- `/mnt/informix/ids` is where am installing IDS.
- `/mnt/informix/storage` is where rootdbs, env.ids have been created.

I was able to create instance on each machine and access the remote instance after providing some changes editing the onconfig file, sqlhosts file and hosts.equiv file on each machine. I've been able to create databases and tables on each machine and establish connection between both of them. But when it is time to configure disk for replication, I am not sure of what am doing. I've created new dbspaces and sbspaces by creating new files inside storage directory and changed owner to informix user and file access permissions to 660, then create dbspaces and sbspaces using the onspaces command and provided the required entries in the onconfig file, but I get the error:

> command failed -- Sbspace specified for the send/receive queue does
>   not exist (107)

Comment: Ummm.. did you bounce the instances after changing the onconfig parameter (CDR_QDATA_SBSPACE)?

Comment: The following Reddook has a really good guide (charter 10) regarding how to setup ER.  "Informix Dynamic Server 11: Extending Availability and Replication" http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247488.html?Open.  It may help.

Comment: @jsagrera how can I bounce the instances ??

Comment: I mean restart the instances (e.g. shutdown with 'onmode -kuy' and start with 'oninit -v')

Comment: I'm a little surprised by the choice of `/mnt` as the directory for installing Informix.  Classically, the choice would be `/usr/informix` (that's still the assumed default).  A more modern choice would be `/opt/informix` — and `/usr/local/informix` could also make sense.  It isn't formally wrong, but normally `/mnt` is used for mounted file systems; all that's in `/mnt` is empty directories where file systems can be mounted (and creating those may be handled automatically).

Comment: i will reinstall informix on the mentionned path but would that make my problem resolved am unable or let s say i dont know how to create dbspaces and sbspaces and how to configure them on the onconfig file because when i ve checked  the online documentation and they say that you have to define sbspaces and dbspace but none mention how to achieve those steps